# My first Scilab algorithm - Horner's method

Tags: algorithm, scilab

this is my first Scilab algorithm (Horner's method). Please tell me what should I correct to make it working (according to this [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PmXZ.jpg)). I am a very beginner. Your feedback will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function
    N=4 //number of elements
    TAB=[4,2,6,5]   //exemplary numbers
    w=a0
    i=1
    while i<=n do
        w=wx+a[i]
        i=i+1
    end
endfunction
```

Comment: please specify what result are you getting and what is expected one

Comment: I have a function: Wn(x)=a0xn+a1xn-1+a2xn-2+.......+an-1x1+anx0. (Horner's method)
And I need to write an algorithm, which gives a value of a polynomial. I already made an iteration flowchart for it and it must be re-written in Scilab

Comment: Why bubblesort ?

Comment: for example: W(x)=4x4+2x3+6x2+5x

Comment: seemed right... if not bubblesort, then what?

Comment: sorry but SO is not a place to get working code for you. Please explain what is wrong with your code and how you have tried to fix it. I understand the algorithm but do not see any effort from your side

Comment: ok sorry. bubblesort has no sense here, I already corrected the code. I don't need to name the function, right? The examplary numbers are needed in the code? Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Where is the array `a[]` defined ? Note also that for n=4, you need to define 5 values

Answer (score 1):

Please, read some introduction (https://www.scilab.org/scilab-real-dummies for example) to Scilab to learn the basics it will help you for the future.

The calling sequence of your function should be something like:

```
 v=myhorner(A,x)
```

where A is the array containing the polynomial coefficients in decreasing order and x the value for which you want to evaluate the polynomial.

Then the code should be

```
 v=A(1); 
 for i=2:size(A,"*")
    v=v*x+A(i);
 end
```

Note however the horner function already exists in Scilab